Get table dynamically with name in excel
I have an excel files with multiples tables, in my case: Calcul, 2024-02, 2024-03, 2024-04 ...
I want to get data from each table according to the month (2024 & 02). Actuall, I'm making =SOMME.SI('2024-02'!B:B;"something";'2024-02'!C:C), but I want to make the 2024-02 part dynamic.
If I put the value 2024-02 somewhere (A1 for example), I can't use it like =SOMME.SI(A1!B:B;"something";A1!C:C), or like =SOMME.SI(CONCAT(A1;!B:B);"something";CONCAT(A1;!C:C))

Use INDIRECT() function! But can you clarify you are referring Tables as in Structured References right, if so then how can you have a table name as 2024-02 or 2024-03 naming conventions won't allow.

@MayukhBhattacharya by table, I mean "xls tab" like multiple tabs

Oh okay sheet tabs you meant right?

@MayukhBhattacharya Yes. With excel, it's hard to have the english word as even method are translated...

Hi @Elikill58 it will be something like this: =SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B:B"),"something",INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C:C")) . are you using DUTCH version then --> =SOM.ALS(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B:B");"something";INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C:C"))

Sorry I think you are using French Version then: =SOMME.SI(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B:B");"something";INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C:C")) let me know if that works

So, you could try using the following formula with a combination of SUMIF()+INDIRECT()
• In English Version of Excel :
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B:B"),"something",INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C:C"))


• In French Version of Excel :
=SOMME.SI(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B:B");"something";INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C:C"))


